# Laravel reset password using Username instead Email

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7, reset-password

I would to reset the password in my project using the `Username` field instead the `Email` one.

I already set login with username field and it works, but not the same for resetting password.

I overrode methods on `ResetPasswordController` with some instructions get online but I can't solve my issue.

Here my code:

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'username', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
        ];
    }
}
```

I also changed `resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php` and `resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php` overriding `username` to all `email` input fields.

Laravel version: 7.x

Any suggestions?

Comment: what isn't working? do you get an error?

Comment: Are you using the default user and password authentication method from laravel?

Comment: After clicking submit button to receive tue reset link by email, nothing happen and on log file nothing is generated.

Comment: @kingbeencent yes, the default auth method

Comment: @Swim89 can you provide the ResetPasswords trait for us?

Comment: The ResetPassword trait is the default one..

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I'm currently having this issue also. it's currently querying the email instead of username